# TFS Build "View Test Results" link not visible to my team

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Using VS 2010, I get the link to the test results from build, but no other team member does.  I can't figure out what setting I have that allows this for me and not for other team members.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to ensure that 'Allow" permission is set for "Team Project Setting > Security > View test runs" for the groups and users. If I remember correctly, each of the four default groups Readers, Contributors, Builders, and Project Administrators has this permission.